# Can not update quote_id field of "quote_item" table magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to assign items added to the cart by one customer to the other customer's cart.

For this, I see two tables responsible for holding that data. One is table named **"quote"** and other is **"Quote_item"**.The customer to which I want to transfer the cart item already has a quote created on the quote table. so I thought changing the quote_id of that customer on the `quote_item` table would do the trick.

**Let me explain by example:**

Let us assume we have two customers with quote id 1 and 2.
Customer 1 added a product to the cart so on the quote_item table the item will be saved with quote id 1. so if I could change the quote id of that item to 2 then that product will be assigned to customer 2.

I tried it by manually changing to the database and it worked. But When I tried to update that table programmatically than it couldn't update the row. I think there is some kind of dependencies that I couldn't figure out. So I hope if someone could help me figure it out.

Below is the updated code that I have written.

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$quoteItemModel = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');
//filter the product with same quote id     
        $productCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId);
            if($products = $productCollection->getData()){
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    $itemId = $product['item_id'];
                    $data = array();
                    //just putting a static value to check if the data gets updated
                    $data['quote_id']='2';
                    //updating the quote_item table
                    $quoteItemModel->load($itemId)->addData($data);
                    try {
                        $quoteItemModel->setId($itemId)->save();
                        echo "Data updated successfully.";

                    } catch (Exception $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage(); 
                     }
                    }
```

I know the code works perfectly with other custom tables. But in this case, it is not updating the data.
Its gives below error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on null in
> E:\xampp\htdocs...\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem.php
> on line 144

When I checked that file. The function is:

```
 public function getProduct()
    {
        $product = $this->_getData('product');
        if ($product === null && $this->getProductId()) {
            $product = clone $this->productRepository->getById(
                $this->getProductId(),
                false,
                $this->getQuote()->getStoreId()
            );
            $this->setProduct($product);
        }
```

I don't understand what it has to do with the update of table quote_item. I think there are some foreign key constraints or some dependency which is why it is not letting me update the **quote_id** of **quote_item** table.

Can some genius mind please help me out here or clarify what could have possibly gone wrong?

I searched the whole internet and also posted questions on StackOverflow about the migration of customer carts from one customer to another but still, I haven't got a perfect working solution for it.

If someone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you want to add this item in one person's cart to another user.

Comment: That's my requirement.actually one customer should be able to assign products to another customer cart.

Answer (score 0):

could you explain more your task ? the customer 1 has to keep his quote and items ? and the customer 2 just have the same items than the customer 1 that's it?
In this case just use the `addProduct` method which take 2 parameters (`$product, $qty`).

Get the items from customer 1's quote. Loop on it, and add product to your customer 2's quote.

Comment: Yes that could be one of the solution. can you post some code snippet. Actually I have complex bundle products with many options, so I guess doing that would be quite difficult. Can you post some code to verify your logic. THanks